# Using nth-child within another nth-child

Tags: html, css, sass

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>heading a</th>
      <th>heading b</th>
      <th>heading c</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>White</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

above is a sample table for this question. So, first to give some context I want to create a table with a frozen first column. I have done that by selecting the first child td of tr and setting the position as absolute and adding a padding to the left.Because of this the css I use to change the background colour of every other row is not available in the first column. Now I want to add a background colour to every other first-child of td so i tried

```
td {
  &:first-child {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
        &:nth-child(even){
          background-color: blue;
          }
    }
}
```

but this still selecting all the first td elements.

My question is why is this showing such a behaviour and is there a way to select the elements the way I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is how you want it?

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) td:first-child {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>heading a</th>
      <th>heading b</th>
      <th>heading c</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

```css
td:first-child {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
tr td:not(:first-child){
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>heading a</th>
      <th>heading b</th>
      <th>heading c</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hi, So when you run this snippet you can see that all the columns other than the first column is changed right. So what I want is the cells in the "heading a" column and in that column also first "data 1" cell to have colour and the next not to have colour and again the third to have colour and so on . I will update the html in the question to better understand

Comment: @chanuka_dsc code is updated please check

Comment: Hi this is not the result I want, can you check the html in the updated question. There I have noted down the <td> elements I want coloured with the name of the colours.

Comment: @chanuka_dsc updated according to your updated question.

Comment: Beautiful, Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused but is this how you want it?

```css
td:first-child {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>heading a</th>
      <th>heading b</th>
      <th>heading c</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that this will apply to the colour to the raws starting from <td> data 2 </td> onwards because the <td>data 1</td> 's are set to position absolute the css rules are ignored I think.